# Is the inverse of a $k$-vector a $k$-vector?

Tags: clifford-algebras, geometric-algebras

In geometric (Clifford) algebra, both $k$-vectors and inhomogeneous multivectors may have inverses, which are unique (if they exist).
I want to prove the following statement.

> Let $A = ⟨A⟩_k$ be a $k$-vector. Is its inverse $A^{-1} = ⟨A^{-1}⟩_k$ necessarily a $k$-vector?

We can prove that $A^{-1}$ is of grade $k$ if we *assume it is homogeneous*. For example, assuming $A^{-1} = ⟨A^{-1}⟩_m$, then from
$$
AA^{-1} = ⟨A⟩_k ⟨A^{-1}⟩_m = ⟨⟨A⟩_k ⟨A^{-1}⟩_m⟩_{|k-m|} + ⟨⟨A⟩_k ⟨A^{-1}⟩_m⟩_{|k-m| + 2} + \cdots + ⟨⟨A⟩_k ⟨A^{-1}⟩_m⟩_{k + m} = 1
$$
we must have that the lowest-grade part $⟨⟨A⟩_k ⟨A^{-1}⟩_m⟩_{|k-m|} = 1$ is one, requiring $k = m$. Thus $A^{-1} = ⟨A^{-1}⟩_k$ is also a $k$-vector.

---

In an effort to restrict the possible grades of $A^{-1}$ given that $A = ⟨A⟩_k$ is a $k$-vector, I have made the following observations (without assuming $A^{-1}$ is homogeneous):

1. If $k$ is even/odd, then so is $A^{-1}$. This follows because the even-subalgebra is closed, and hence for $AA^{-1} = 1$ we have either $(\text{even})(\text{even}) = (\text{even})$ or $(\text{odd})(\text{odd}) = (\text{even})$.
2. If $\tilde{A} = (-1)^{k(k - 1)/2} A$ is the reverse of $A$, then $\tilde{A^{-1}} = (-1)^{k(k - 1)/2}A^{-1}$ follows from $\widetilde{AA^{-1}} = \tilde{A^{-1}}\tilde{A} = 1$. This implies that $A^{-1}$ may only contain parts of grade $\{ m \in \mathbb{Z} \mid (-1)^{k(k - 1)/2} = (-1)^{m(m - 1)/2}\}$.
3. Combining the two points above, we conclude that if $A = ⟨A⟩_k$ then $A^{-1}$ may only contain parts of grade $k + 4\mathbb{Z}$.
4. In view of the last point, and the fact that (pseudo)scalars and (pseudo)vectors always square to a scalar (and hence have an inverse of the same grade), we can conclude that $A^{-1}$ must be a $k$-vector in algebras of dimension $\le 7$.

But in $8$ dimensions, I can't eliminate the possibility that a $2$-vector has an inverse with parts of grade $6$, and vice versa.

Is there a more direct way to show this, or is there a counter example?

Comment: Warning: My logic in points 3. and 4. about it holding true for dimensions ≤ 7 is wrong… see the answer!

Answer (score 3):

### The inverse of a $k$-vector is not necessarily a $k$-vector !

To my astonishment, I have found a counterexample.

Consider the $6$ dimensional bivector
$$
a ≔ _{12} + _{34} + _{56}
$$
whose dual (with $I ≔ _{123456}$) is
$$
Ia = aI = -(_{3456} + _{1256} + _{1234})
$$
and whose square is
$$
a^2 = -3 + 2(_{3456} + _{1256} + _{1234}) = -3 - 2aI
$$
and whose inverse is
$$
b ≔ -\frac{a + 2I}{3}
$$
as verified by
$$
ab = - \frac{a^2 + 2aI}{3} = \frac{(3 + 2aI) - 2aI}{3} = 1
$$
$\square$

Comment: $aI \ne Ia$, in even dimensions it is $aI = -Ia$. I'm not sure if that matters for your counterexample or not, I'll have to study it more carefully later. Something I'm also not sure of is whether or not right inverse $\implies$ left inverse since $\mathrm{Cl}_6(\mathbb R) \cong M_3(\mathbb H)$. Can you pinpoint anywhere where my proof of the converse is incorrect? It seems too simple to be incorrect.

Comment: Sorry, the very first thing I said was wrong; $a$ and $I$ commute because $a$ is a bivector, not a vector.

Comment: It’s definitely the case that $AA^{-1} = 1 ⟺ A^{-1}A = 1$ in geometric algebra… but I can’t prove it other than by saying “GAs are like a matrix algebras, and they have two-sided inverses, thus so do GAs”.

I.e., any GA over a $d$-dimensional vector space over $ℝ$ has a linear representation in $2^d × 2^d$ matrices, and we know $AA^{-1} = I ⟺ A^{-1}A = I$ for matrices over $ℝ$…

Comment: Yeah, I think this counterexample is correct.

Comment: The proof contained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4630060/in-geometric-algebra-does-a-tilde-a-0-imply-tilde-aa-0) should apply to a one-sided inverse of $A$ and shows that it is necessarily a two-sided inverse; the only requirement seems to be that our algebra is finite dimensional.

Comment: Just for fun: we can find that $$b = \frac{-1}9a^3 -\frac{10}9a$$ and hence $$0 = a^4 + 10a^2 + 9.$$